# ElasticSearch con spring error al mapear con Geopoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, elasticsearch

Cuando Spring trae los documentos de elastic me arroja la siguiente exception
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint]

El problema esta mas detallado en el github del repositorio original con imagenes y codigo (esta en ingles, si se necesita traduccion avisar porfavor).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucion:
Crear un mapper para el tipo geo_point ya que elastic search lo esta devolviendo como un String

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2016

Comment: Me ha pasado lo mismo cargando los datos con logstash, pero como no conozco Spring no comenté. Tambien tuve que crear un mapping del indice especificando los campos geo_point y/o geo_shape.